# How to format FAT32 filesystem infected with windows virus and that is write protected

Tags: filesystem, usb-drive, format, fat32

I have a pendrive with FAT32 filesystem. it is infected with virus dont know which but has autorun.inf and create exe file within folder. I tried to format it with various filesystems and even try to delete it with GParted but couldn't because it says it is write protected i can't even delete files. How to format it?

user@explorerx:~$ sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbd04bd04

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         498     3998720   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             499       19457   152287585+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5            5100       10198    40957686    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6           10199       14787    36861111    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda7           14788       19457    37511743+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda8             499        5099    36956160   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdc: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc13bc13b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1        9729    78143488    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdc2            9729       19457    78143488    7  HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 4194 MB, 4194304000 bytes
112 heads, 47 sectors/track, 1556 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 5264 * 512 = 2695168 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               2        1557     4091904    b  W95 FAT32
```

updates to karthick87

user@explorerx:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

```
WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
     switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
     sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)

E
```

Comment: Are you sure that you unmount the drive before formatting?Also does your usb drive have a switch on it that converts it to write protected?

Comment: yes i unmounted drive and there is no any switch it's Transcend 4.0GB China made

Comment: Look at this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_7284901_format-new-disk-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything fails you may need to run the proprietary recovery tool from [Transcend](http://www.transcend-uk.com/Products/online_recovery_2.asp?dw=1) to sort of low level reformat your pendrive.

Unfortunately this tool requires **Windows**, and in addition you need your **product serial number (S/N)** (in my case this was printed on the product's blister only). You need to contact Transcend in case you lost your S/N.

Answer (score 1):

did you try:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```

dev should NOT be mounted

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple. Be sure the drive is unmounted and then delete the current partition after which you will need to create a new partition. I found a pretty good tutorial on how to do this. Worked for me. [How to Reformat and Partition a Disk in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforum.webs.com/harddiskpartition.htm)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.